# Column doesn't exist in Heroku postgresql database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, heroku

I am working on my first heroku web-app using python and flask. I have it connected to a SQLite database locally and postgresql database through heroku. When running SQL commands in Heroku, I am able to query all of the data from another table, but when I try to access data from the "user" table, it says there is no column named "username", even though in the explorer it shows a column with the same name:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Does this mean my table is empty and the users aren't being added? I'm not getting any errors when adding the users in the app. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"user" is a reserved word in postgresql, so when you're querying that user table, your query isn't going exactly where you expect. Specifying the full table name with its schema should work, which in your case is probably `public.user`.

So your query would look like this:

```
SELECT "username"
FROM public.user;
```

Another way of dealing with this is to surround "user" with quotation marks, like this:

```
SELECT "username"
FROM "user";
```